# minishift start using virtualbox on windows throws timeout error

Tags: minishift

I am trying to start minishift on my machine. It successfully creates minishift VM but throws time out error.

Configuration:

**Minishift version: v1.34.0+f5db7cb**

**OS: Windows 10**

**Hypervisor: Virtual Box v6.0.10**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minishift start

-- Starting OpenShift cluster .......................................................................Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --image 'openshift/origin-${component}:v3.11.0' --public-hostname 192.168.99.100 --routing-suffix 192.168.99.100.nip.io --base-dir /var/lib/minishift/base
err : exit status 1
output : Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Pulling image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0
E0725 17:15:42.919928 5316 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0 anonymously
Image pull complete
E0725 17:15:44.643860 5316 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0 anonymously
Pulling image openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
Pulled 5/6 layers, 85% complete
Pulled 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Extracting
Image pull complete
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Using public hostname IP 192.168.99.100 as the host IP
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
I0725 17:16:20.775520 5316 config.go:40] Running "create-master-config"
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 ...
I0725 17:16:31.108342 5316 config.go:46] Running "create-node-config"
I0725 17:16:35.237968 5316 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I0725 17:16:36.785234 5316 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I0725 17:16:37.288388 5316 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
E0725 17:21:37.300062 5316 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connect: connection refused ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Expected result: It should provide me without errors link to open web console

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me sometimes too.

Solutions include:

- `minishift stop && minishift start` (turn it off and on again)
- restart Windows (perhaps VBox has corrupted itself again)

More info on my minishift setup is here:

http://divby0.blogspot.com/2019/07/configuring-minishift-for-use-with.html

For what it's worth I use a combination of linux shells in Windows 10 to interact with minishift / docker daemon:

- Git Bash (usually the best)
- Docker Toolbox (plan B when something won't run in Git Bash shell)
- WSL (ubuntu based, plan C in desperation)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I am able to run minishift on my machine for now. But it is not consistent. So couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I had the 8443 problem and after restarting my Windows 10 machine it curiously started the Openshift correctly. I had followed the instructions in this Red Hat site: https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world#fndtn-windows